# Unable to redirect from index.html to a Perl script

Tags: apache, cgi-bin

My web server directories are:

/var/www/cgi-bin
/var/www/example.com/public_html

In my sites-enabled conf file I have:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
 <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/">
     Options +ExecCGI
     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
 </Directory>
```

In my index.html redirect to the index.pl file with:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://example.com/cgi-bin/uploadstart.pl'">
```

The files permissions are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 umast   www-data       749 Feb 10 22:34 uploadstart.pl
```

I can run the script via command line directly within the cgi-bin directory.

Yet from my browser I still get:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at warptv.com Port 80

Looking at example.com-error.log I see:

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration

I know I am missing something. It's been a while, but I was even sure that the group and owner could both be umast.

What am I missing?

Comment: After many searches on line I added ' Require all granted' ` to the cgi section of the example.com.conf.  While that worked, I want to make sure I didn't open something I shouldn't have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
<Directory /var/www/cgi-bin">
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

will make Apache serve files inside that directory.

Comment: See comment above my question, but thanks for letting me know that was the right move

Comment: No, please. Am glad you responded. I found that answer out of many tried. But I wasn't sure it was the **correct** answer. Fort all I knew I just opened up my entire server to the public.